# Get value of special attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I gave my `<img>` a special `attribute` like this:

```
<img src="image.png" _percent="0.01">
```

Now I want to get the value of `_percent` with jQuery (or basic javascript)
I tried

```
$("img").attr("_percent");
```

but this returns `undefined`.

Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't use attributes like that but do this:

```
<img src="image.png" data-percent="0.01">
```

and then:

```
$("img").data("percent");
```

Comment: Hm, I was taught differently :D thanks for telling me, this works! Will try using data in the future.

Comment: You should use the `data` attribute for anything that isn't a default attribute on an element for browser compatibility. Before people used the `rel` attribute quite a lot, but you shouldn't anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not liking your `_percent` attribute.  I would use a data- attribute instead:

```
<img src="image.png" data-percent="0.01">
```

and then

```
$("img").attr("data-percent");
```

or even

```
$("img").data("percent");
```

---

Just note that, if you have more than one image anywhere on your page, either of the above ways of accessing your percent value will only give you the value attached to the **first** image jQuery finds.  But I assume this was just a simplified piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the data attribute is for.

```
<img src="image.png" data-percent="0.01">
```

`$("img").attr("data-percent");`